# Anything inside formview is not displaying asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

Anything inside the formview is not displaying, I am not sure if it's because its inside div? 
I tried to add labels but stil had no luck, please help.

```
    <asp:formview id="my" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmpID"  DataSourceID="SQLEmpl">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                    <div runat= "server" class="heading">My Details</div>
                     <div class="myfield">
                        <div class="name">Name</div>
                        <div class="fielddetails"><asp:label id="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'>  </asp:label></div>
                    </div>
...
```

Comment: Whats in your datasource control can you add the code

Answer (score 0):

Checklist

1. Check whether the datasource has data in it.
2. Check if it is not set to display: none in css/ hide() in jQuery or visible = false from c#

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have called [DataBind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxh3ys50.aspx)

If your datasource has data, this is the most likely source.
You need to call this after you called DataBind() on your data source. A good place to this is Page load.

```
my.DataBind()
```